# How to Define a Variable to Be Used Only Within the Given .GS File - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Suppose you have two sheets, say "Boys" and "Girls", and two corresponding .gs files "Boys.gs" and "Girls.gs".

In Boys.gs, we've declared a variable `classID` to be the value located in cell `B7` of the sheet "Boys":

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
var sheetBoys = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Boys');

var classID = sheetBoys.getRange('B7');
```

In Girls.gs, we also want to declare the variable `classID`, but now we want it to be the value located in cell `B9` of the sheet "Girls":

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
var sheetGirls = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Girls');

var classID = sheetGirls.getRange('B9');
```

Both Boys.gs and Girls.gs contain *multiple functions* that utilize `classID`.

**Objective**

I'd like to use the variable `classID` defined in Boys.gs across **all** functions in Boys.gs. Similarly, I'd like to use the variable `classID` defined in Girls.gs across **all** functions in Girls.gs.

**Issue**

I currently have to define `classID` repeatedly in every Boys.gs and/or Girls.gs function which uses it. If I define it outside of the functions, then I have two definitions across the two different files.

*Of Note:*
As far as I understand, I can't nest the functions on each .gs inside a master function because I have tied specific functions to specific "buttons" in the spreadsheet, as well as to OnEdit and OnOpen functions.

Is there a way to define the variable to be used only within the functions on the given .gs file?

Comment: Try changing the classID to include differentiating between girls and boys and in that way you can use the same global variable for both girls and boys.  Use the PropertiesService to load the global variable each time a function is called.  That way the initialization of the variable can be different each time.  Of course the first function that uses it will have to save the value in the PropertiesService object so that next time it's used it's up to date.   This could lead to difficulties if multiple users are using the same script.

Comment: There is no script-file level scope for variables declared in Apps Script. Why don't you just declare `boysClassID` and `girlsClassID`, the same way you did with sheets? It's less of a mess than any workaround I can think of.

Comment: Ok thank you. Sounds like no good way to do it except different variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no script-file level scope for variables declared in Apps Script. Therefore, there's no way to define a variable to be used only within the function on a given `.gs` file. Any variable defined outside of a function will be accessible to any function in any of the `.gs` files in your project.

Therefore, if you don't want to declare the variable inside every function, I'd just declare two different variables (in the example you provided, something like `boysClassID` and `girlsClassID`). Any workaround I can think of (for example, the use of [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service), as mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369510/how-to-define-a-variable-to-be-used-only-within-the-given-gs-file-apps-script#comment122611130_69369510)) seems more of a mess than this, as long as the number of these variables is kept relatively low.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Just wanted to know if there was a better option so good to know this is the simplest way.